# Request to EdgeCast REST API from Python return 405 'Method not allowed'

Tags: python, rest

I'm trying to automate purging of files on Edgecast through their REST API.

This code works within a Bash script:

```
curl -s  -H "Authorization: tok:$EC_AUTH_TOKEN" -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT -d "{ \"MediaPath\":\"$PURGE_PATH\", \"MediaType\":3 }"  https://api.edgecast.com/v2/mcc/customers/$ACCT_ID/edge/purge
```

But this Python version does not:

```
def purge_file(file_path):
buff = StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
post_data = {'MediaPath': file_path, 'MediaType': 3}
# Form data must be provided already urlencoded.
postfields = json.dumps(post_data, separators=(',', ':'))
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, postfields)
c.setopt(c.URL, PURGE_URL)
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: tok:' + EC_AUTH_TOKEN,
                             'Accept: application/json',
                             'Content-Type: application/json'])
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buff)
c.perform()
c.close()
body = buff.getvalue()
print (body)
```

Nor does this:

```
def purge_file(file_path):
values = {'MediaPath': urllib.quote_plus(file_path),
          'MediaType': 3}
post_data = json.dumps(values, separators=(',', ':'))
request = urllib2.Request(PURGE_URL, data=post_data, headers={'Accept': 'application/json',
                                                              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                                              'Authorization': 'tok:' + EC_AUTH_TOKEN})
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
print response.read()
```

Both of the Python versions return an error 405: Method not allowed.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target API expects a `PUT` request. You're sending a `POST` request. That's why it's throwing this error.

You can add this to send the data as a `PUT` request:

```
c.setopt(pycurl.CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT")
```

But I strongly recommend using the awesome [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library to handle REST calls. A sample `PUT` request would look like this:

```
requests.put("http://httpbin.org/put", data = {"key":"value"})
```

Comment: D'oh!  Thanks for the help!